# How to add interceptor around materialization in EF 6

Tags: entity-framework, interceptor

some time ago I managed to add a custom interceptor to a private fork of EF 6.1 that gets called just before and after a lazy-loading DB-Hit is performed, like this:

```
public interface IDbLazyLoadInterceptor : IDbInterceptor
{
    void LazyLoadablePropertyGetterCalled<TItem>(DbLazyLoadInterceptionContext<TItem> interceptionContext) where TItem : class;
    void PropertyIsGettingLazyLoaded<TItem>(DbLazyLoadInterceptionContext<TItem> interceptionContext) where TItem : class;
    void PropertyHasBeenLazyLoaded<TItem>(DbLazyLoadInterceptionContext<TItem> interceptionContext) where TItem : class;
}
```

Now I have a new requirement. I need to create an interceptor that gets called by EF just before and just after the materialization of entities is/has been performed. Problem: I want to be able to correlate this to DB Hits (stuff getting called to `IDbCommandInterceptor`).

I need help about where to start.

I thought I could add interceptor-dispatch-calls into the Shaper, e.g. into its `public bool MoveNext()` and `public async Task<bool> MoveNextAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)` methods, before and after it calls `_shaper.StartMaterializingElement();` and `_shaper.StopMaterializingElement();`. I guess this could work, right?

But how can I correlate this to the Db Command fed to the `IDbCommandInterceptor`? Is there some way to get the Command (query?) run by the Reader used by the Shaper?

And: Am I missing further spots I'd need to add interceptor-calls to?

Thanks, cheers,
Tim